# How to change the format of Last seen: in author pane in advanced forum?

Tags: 7, nodes

I have installed Advanced forum and Author pane module. Now, I did found the option of date format for Joined:__________, But not able to find the date format for Last Seen:________, The Last seen option shown very granular details like, Last Seen: 1 min 20 sec ago, I just want like,

```
Last Seen: 1 min ago

Last Seen: 2 hr ago

Last Seen: 1 day ago

Last Seen: dd/mm/yyyy
```

Comment: You would have to create your own custom time ago using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to use:

```
function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_author_pane(&$variables) {
  // Get the number of seconds since last login.
  $time_since_last_login = REQUEST_TIME - $variables['account']->access;
  // Custom override of the "last_active" variable.
  //
  // This is just an example; add your rules here.
  if ($time_since_last_login < 120 * 60) {
    // Show 2hr ago for any interval within last 2 hours.
    $variables['last_active'] = t('2 hours ago');
  }
  else {
    $variables['last_active'] = format_date('short', $variables['account']->access);
  }
}
```

Just add your custom time formatting rules.

Comment: Well, as far as i understand, it will display, 2 hr ago, when last seen time is less then 2 hr. But that is not what I need, It should show 1min-60min, 1hr -24 year, onward--Date. Thanks though for answer, appreciated.

Comment: See [format_interval()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/format_interval/7) function; if you don't figure it out, I'll have a look in the morning :)